# NumberFormatException using BufferReader

Tags: java

How to deal with `NumberFormatException`? Whenever I type the input, no error happens but when I **copy** it to the to console, I used to get an exception.

Here's the piece of code I'm referring to:

```
package one;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


class A {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws IOException, 
                                                   NumberFormatException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        // int t=Integer.parseInt( br.readLine());

        String line = br.readLine().trim();
        int t = Integer.valueOf(line);
        int f[]=new int[t];


        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        f[i]=fib();
        }

        for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
        System.out.println(f[i]);
    }

    static int fib() throws IOException ,NumberFormatException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line = br.readLine().trim();

        int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        //int n=Integer.valueOf(line);

        int a=1,b=2;int c;

        if(n==1) return a;
        if (n==2) return b;
        else {
            do {
                c=a+b;
                a=b;
                b=c;
                n--;
            } while(n>2);
        }
        return c%1000000007;
    } 
}
```

This program tries to find the nth term of the Fibonacci series.

Comment: On which line exactly are you getting the error and what is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Can you give a specific example of input that causes this error?

Comment: Are you really passing number to `parseInt(br.readLine())`? method?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are skipping every other line, because you are calling br.readLine() twice in fib().

```
   String line = br.readLine().trim();
   int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

Also, you are repeatedly creating new BufferedReaders, `t + 1` in total.  Since it's a BufferedReader, I don't think the behavior is well defined.  You're repeatedly reading chunks of System.in - paying attention to only the second line - then ignoring the reader and creating a new one in the next iteration.

Comment: @shekharsuman Thanks!  It's interesting how different the two communities are from each other.